# Por que se cierra el prompt antes de que pueda escribir un dato? (en javascript)

Tags: javascript

> Quisiera saber por que se cierra en consola el prompt

```
    var nombre = "Juan";
    var apellido = "Lopez";
    var valorHora = 3785;
    var valorHoraExtra = 4731;
    var salario = 0;
    var maximohoras = 8;
    var horasTrabajadas = prompt("ingres cantidad de horas: ");

> este prompt se me cierra solo al ejecutarlo en consola, no alcanzo a escribir el valor
    
    function totalSalario(salario) {
      if (horasTrabajadas > maximohoras) {
        var salario = valorHora * horasTrabajadas + valorHoraExtra;
        console.log(`El salario del usuario ${nombre} ${apellido} es: ${salario}`);
      } else if(horasTrabajadas < maximohoras){
          var salario = valorHora * horasTrabajadas;
        console.log(
          `El usuario trabajo, no hizo horas extras y su salario es:  ${salario}`
        )
      }
    }
```

> Agradezco la asesoria que me puedan prestar, tanto para solucionar el problema, como para mejorar mi codigo.
> muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Deberías checar tu código, pues lo que expones no tiene el comportamiento que indicas

Comment: Gracias, si estoy empezando y pues me di a la tarea de hacer ejercicios por mi mismo, y lo que quiero llegar a hacer, es ingresar los datos que me queden guardados en una variable, y después realizar una operación que calcule estos datos para imprimir. Depronto me podrías guiar?

Comment: Tal cual dice BetaM.. el código que expones no se cierra... así que debes tener algo mas que cause que se cierre

Comment: Si es verdad, no termine de copiar todo el codigo, pidos disculpas. 
Hola, si, que pena con uds no habia puesto todo el codigo completo. Pido disculpas por el codigo

var nombre = "Juan";
var apellido = "Lopez";
var valorHora = 3785;
var valorHoraExtra = 4731;
var salario = 0;
var maximohoras = 8;
var horasTrabajadas = prompt("ingres cantidad de horas: ");
function totalSalario(salario) {
if (horasTrabajadas > maximohoras){
var salario = valorHora * horasTrabajadas + valorHoraExtra;
console.log(`El salario del usuario ${nombre} ${apellido} es: ${salario}`)

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para completar el código en la pregunta y explicar con claridad cuál es el problema o error que estás teniendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo probé tu código y me funciona correctamente, no se me cierra el prompt.

Consejo.

No utilices la palabra reservada **var** ya que dejas abierto el ámbito léxico pueda actuar en su máximo esplendor y eso puede traerte problemas.

Te recomiendo solo uses *let* y **const**, mi otro consejo es que te acostumbres a escribir código en inglés, te ayudara mucho en el futuro.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu recomendación. apenas termine de leer tu mensaje y lo hice y se ve mucho mejor. No se por que se me cerrar, no dura mas de 2segundos abierto. Pero estoy muy agradecido por tus mensaje. Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que tu interpretas como que *se cierra* es que en realidad no estás viendo ningún resultado del código que has escrito, esto es principalmente porque no has invocado a la función `totalSalario()`, por lo tanto, su código nunca se ejecuta (y no produce ninguna salida).

Dicho esto, veo varios problemas:

- la función accede a variables globales, (externas a ella). Mientras esto es permitido, no siempre es una buena práctica. Sobre todo en tiempos modernos dónde hay promesas y los valores pueden cambiar mientras se está ejecutando la función. Además, como verás más adelante, también puede provocar confusión por el traslape de nombres de variables. En lo personal, prefiero generalmente pasar los valores como parámetros de la función, de esta manera queda claro con qué valores está operando (los que tenían las variables al momento de la llamada).
- Si pretendes calcular el salario, como más o menos indica el nombre de la función, entonces esta debiera retornar un valor y no lo hace.
- Quizás creas que has dejado el valor en la variable global `salario`, pero, de la forma que está escrita la función, lo que haces es declarar nuevas variables `salario`, cuyo ámbito es solamente dentro del `then` (la primera) y dentro del `else` la segunda. El valor que asignas a esas variables no se verá reflejado en la variable global `salario`, se pierde al salir del `then` o del `else`.
- La estructura del `if` deja por fuera el caso de que las horas trabajadas sea exactamente igual al máximo, no hace falta el segundo `if` a menos que hubiese 3 formas distintas de cálculo.

Corrigiendo esos detalles, con esto verás el resultado del código (clic en el botón *"Ejecutar"* para verlo aquí mismo en el navegador):

```js
var nombre = "Juan";
var apellido = "Lopez";
var valorHora = 3785;
var valorHoraExtra = 4731;
var salario = 0;
var maximohoras = 8;
var horasTrabajadas = prompt("ingres cantidad de horas: ");
    
salario = calcularSalario(nombre, apellido, valorHora, valorHoraExtra, maximohoras, horasTrabajadas);
console.log("fin.");

function calcularSalario(nombre, apellido, valorHora, valorHoraExtra, maximohoras, horasTrabajadas) {
   var result = 0;
   if (horasTrabajadas > maximohoras) {
      result = valorHora * horasTrabajadas + valorHoraExtra;
   } else {
      result = valorHora * horasTrabajadas;
   }
   console.log(`El salario del usuario ${nombre} ${apellido} es: ${result}`);
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Buenos días desde mi país. Amigo, muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta, me aclaraste muchas dudas, y el aporte con respecto a la variable que encierra todos los datos en calcuclarSalario me parece brutal. Así que muchisimas gracias por tu aporte, aprendí mucho. y creeme que ya mismo lo pongo en practica. Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda. Dados tus buenos comentarios y falta de otras acciones, me temo que quizás no sepas [que puedes hacer cuando alguien responde tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Nada de esto es obligatorio, te lo dejo aquí de manera informativa. Un saludo.

Comment: Es cierto llevo, solo días en la plataforma, entonces apenas estoy aprendiendo. Te agradezco la información! Empezare a ponerlos en practica. Muchísimas gracias!